# Auto format where block in Spock testing?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, spock

When writing  spock test is there a way I can auto format the where block in Eclipse?

```
where:
    name      | length
    "Spock"   | 2
    "Java"    | 5
    "Groovy"  | 6
```

Without having to hit Tabs and spaces all the time.

Comment: There are some solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/151034/190201

Answer (score 2):

Auto-formatting of data tables would make a good feature request for the [Eclipse Spock plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spock-plugin). IntelliJ supports it out-of-the-box.

Comment: I'm not aware of any.